# How to Group By Qty in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

[image]

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to get group by qty as describe in image attached.

[EDITED IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRGli.jpg)

Comment: select QTY,count(*) from table group by QTY

Comment: @shankarsh15 thank for you response. what about if i also need group by date as well ?

Comment: Then please run this query:  select QTY,DATE,count(*) from table group by QTY,DATE

Comment: @shankarsh15 it's not returning what is my requirements. For Example I want to count Qty: 51 on date '2016-05-22'.

Comment: @shankarsh15. can you guide further to get COUNT(qty) date wise as well

Comment: I am not very clear what exactly you are looking out for, can you show it with an example in a tabular format as shown above, do u want to do sum of quantity?

Comment: @shankarsh15, Please check my EDITED image above

Comment: so this one: select DATE,QTY,count(*) from table group by DATE,QTY    does not work?

Comment: @shankarsh15, No it's not giving TOTAL COUNT. SEE HERE

'DATE QTY COUNT
2016-01-10 10:21:22.000 0 1
2016-01-10 10:21:26.000 0 1
2016-01-10 10:21:29.000 0 2
2016-01-10 10:21:31.000 0 1
2016-01-10 10:21:32.000 0 1
2016-01-10 10:21:33.000 0 1'

Comment: select CAST(date as DATE),QTY,count(*) from table group by CAST(date as DATE),QTY

Comment: @shankarsh15, that's fine now... Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select QTY,count(*) from table group by QTY
```